# QueryString Parameters in Mvc strongly typed actionlinks

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I think there is no overload available to add parameters other than the action parameters list while creating actionlink through strongly typed action links. What I want is to add extra parameters which will be available in querystring . 
For example with action **MyAction(int id)** in controller **MyController**. 
**Html.ActionLink(mc=>mc.MyAction(5),"My Action")** will produce link something like **MyController/MyAction/5** but what I want is append querystring like this.
**MyController/MyAction/5?QS=Value**. Is there any way,using strongly typed actionlinks, to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

```
<%=Html.ActionLink(LinkName, Action, Controller, new { param1 = value1, param2 = value2 }, new { })%>
```

Comment: I was doing this:@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Create" & "?parID=Automatic&parController=" & ViewData("Action").ToString, "Controller", New With {.area = "MyArea"}, New With {.class = "imgNew"}), this work in MVC2, but when I try to do the same on MVC3 i get this error: **A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client**. Obviouslly the parameter were the problem so I correct to: @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Create", "Controller", New With {.area = "MyArea", .parID = "Automatic", .parController = ViewData("Action").ToString}, New With {.class = "imgNew"}).

Answer (score 1):

Create custom helper for this. Try something like this:

```
public static string MyActionLinkWithQuery<TController>(this HtmlHelper helper, Expression<Action<TController>> action, string linkText,
    RouteValueDictionary query) where TController : Controller
{
    RouteValueDictionary routingValues = ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression(action);

    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in query)
        routingValues.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

    return helper.RouteLink(linkText, routingValues, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create extension methods, just change your routing configuration:

```
  routes.MapRoute(null,
       "MyController/MyAction/{id}",
        new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction", id="" } // Defaults
       );


        routes.MapRoute(
       null
      , // Name
       "{controller}/{action}", // URL
       new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction" } // Defaults
       );
```